# Extracting packed data using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I have data in a database in the format below:

```
a:19:{s:9:"raceclass";a:5:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:7:"250cc B";}i:1;a:1:{i:1;s:6:"OPEN B";}i:2;a:1:{i:2;s:9:"Plus 25 B";}i:3;a:1:{i:3;s:8:"Vet 30 B";}i:4;a:1:{i:4;s:7:"Vintage";}}s:9:"firstname";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:5:"James";}}s:12:"middle_FIELD";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:1:"R";}}s:8:"lastname";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:9:"Slaughter";}}s:5:"email";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:29:"jslaughter@xtrememxseries.com";}}s:8:"address1";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:18:"21 DiMartino Court";}}s:4:"city";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:6:"Walden";}}s:5:"state";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:8:"New York";}}s:3:"zip";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:5:"12586";}}s:7:"country";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:13:"United States";}}s:6:"gender";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:4:"Male";}}s:3:"dob";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:10:"06/04/1974";}}s:5:"phone";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:12:"845-713-4421";}}s:5:"skill";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:12:" AMATEUR (B)";}}s:11:"ridernumber";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:2:"69";}}s:8:"bikemake";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:3:"HON";}}s:8:"enginecc";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:3:"450";}}s:9:"amanumber";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:7:"1094649";}}s:10:"amaexpdate";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:5:"03/12";}}}
```

How can I write a regular expression to manipulate the above string to get data in the following format?:

```
raceclass - 250cc B, OPEN B, Plus 25 B, Vet30, Vintage
firstname - James
middle_FIELD - R
address1 = 21 DiMartino Court
city - walden
state - New york
zip - 12586
country - United States
gender - Male
dob - 06/04/1974
phone - 845-713-4421
skill - AMATEUR (B)
ridernumber - 69
bikemake - HON
enginecc - 450
amanumber - 1094649
amaexpdate - 03/12
```

Comment: So do you want everything contained between double quotes in that string? One regex cannot do that, btw.

Comment: What kind of data format is *that*?

Comment: @m0skit0, the double quoted strings don't make the syntax non-regular.  You just have to use two groups per-field.

Comment: I didn't say you can't do it with regex. I meant you cannot extract ALL the double-quoted strings executing only one regex once.

Answer (score 0):

This data isn't suitable for a regular expression. You should use a proper parser with a proper grammar for handling this string. There are several good options for that in Java, such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

Alternatively, if that is not an option it looks like you only want to handle things between "". Take a look at the java class [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). You should be able to get something working with that. Just look through the string and look for a `"`. If found start to gather text into a buffer. Once you have found another `"` ignore tokens until you have found the next `"` or the end of the input text.

Comment: You are right. I need everything contained between double quotes in that string. I did tried the following java code : Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(paramsString);}
   
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
   lst.add(m.group(1));